# Can I add an outside switch to exterior floodlights?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have an exterior floodlight that is switched from inside the house. I want to be able to switch it on at its outside location, as well. I don't want a motion detector light. I hope I can avoid additional wiring work. The floodlight is well protected from weather, mounted under an overhang on the outside of the house. Location is southwest USA.

Comment: You'll have to change to 3-way switches, which will likely require you to install an additional conductor. Not likely you'll be able to do this without pulling cable.

Comment: You can use 2 switches in series without pulling cable -- in operation you just leave the inside switch on all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a remotely controlled wall switch. This comes in 2 parts.  One is a switch that replaces your current indoor switch.  The other is a remote control unit that wirelessly controls the switch.  This approach does not require any additional wiring indoors or out.  Just google "remote controlled wall switch" to see the various options available.

Comment: there are several options for this. X10 is the old standard I do this for a Tenant that has shared space access. Luton and Leviton also make Remote switches that are battery operated. they are surface mount and you stick them anywhere.

Comment: Yep this was my thought as well -- but *do not use X10*, it is really, really awful. Use Insteon or something Z-wave-based (Lutron and Leviton are increasingly using Z-wave), if you're going to go that route. Nice thing with these types of systems is you can later add motion detectors (multiples, if you want), as well as controllers that can do simple time-based schedules or complex actions based on time/motion/switches.